# Making ISO_Level5_Shift work

Tags: xkb

With lines such as

```
key <AD01> { [     q,          Q,        degree,        paragraph ] };
```

in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`, I am able to access the degree symbol with
ISO_Level3_Shift+q.  I thought that adding a fifth item would make it
accessible with `ISO_Level5_Shift+q`, but that does nothing (outputs `q`).  In
fact, adding a fifth breaks level 3 too.  How can I make use of the extra
modifier?  Running Arch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to quixotic's comment I found it works after one has added

```
key.type[Group1] = "EIGHT_LEVEL";
```

under the `name[Group1]=` line.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there.  You'd get `¶` with <kbd>ISO_Lv3_Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> -- that's the fourth level.

```
// ISO level   1  2    3         4       5    6    7    8
key <AD01> { [ q, Q, degree, paragraph, foo, bar, baz, bat ] };
```

To access all those symbols you'll need <kbd>Shift</kbd> and 3 modifiers:

- no mod gives you `q`; add <kbd>Shift</kbd> for `Q`
- <kbd>ISO_Lv3_Shift</kbd> gives you `°`; add <kbd>Shift</kbd> for `¶`
- <kbd>ISO_Lv5_Shift</kbd> gives you `foo`; add <kbd>Shift</kbd> for `bar`
- <kbd>ISO_Lv3_Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ISO_Lv5_Shift</kbd> gives you `baz`; add <kbd>Shift</kbd> for `bat`

I believe in some contexts you may see the combination of <kbd>ISO_Lv3_Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ISO_Lv5_Shift</kbd> referred to as `ISO_Lv8_Shift` or `level8`.

Comment: I should have made it clearer that, if I add a fifth item, this is not accessible with lv5.  In fact, adding a fifth item breaks lv3 as well.

Comment: @toothrot probably the layout you're modifying is defined as `FOUR_LEVEL_*` so it's ignoring the extra levels.  try basing your variant on an existing layout that's already using higher levels (`grep` existing symbols files for `EIGHT_LEVEL_`).  explicitly setting an XKB option like `lv5:<whatever>` may enable it.

Comment: @Toothrot and i'm afraid that's as far as i can assist you; this level (ha!) of XKB stuff is largely theoretical for me.  if you can clarify your post with exactly what you've tried (`setxkbmap -query`), exactly what modifications you've made to what files, and exactly what you're expecting, we might be better able to assist.